# Visual Studio thinks RavenDB is my code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ravendb

RavenDB throws tons of handled and expected exceptions internally. I have Enable Just My Code checked. I've tried clearing my symbol cache, but if I have Debug > Exceptions > Common Language Runtime Exceptions > Thrown checked, Visual Studio still breaks on these internal RavenDB exceptions.

Why does Visual Studio think RavenDB qualifies as "Just My Code"?

Comment: It is supposed to break.  All that "Just My Code" does when you have the Thrown check turned on is show *your* code, highlighted in green, instead of the RavenDB code that threw the exception.  It is not clear what you actually see.

Comment: So I'm screwed? I can't legitmately debug just my code? I feel like I've seen the just my code option behave otherwise.... I thought it works like DebuggerNonUser code for code you don't have the source to...